# Confusion over indexing and labels in Neo4j (py2neo)

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I have been trying to understand the difference between old indexes and current indexing scheme in Neo4j and I have trouble understanding whether I actually need to use `graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node` or not. I have an example and I would appreciate if someone could point out what is the difference between 2 approaches.

USING INDEXES:

```
patients = graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node,"patients")
doctors=graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node,"doctors")

p1 = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node("patients", "p1", "disease1", {"p1":"disease1", "gender" : "F"})

p2 = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node("patients", "p2", "disease2", {"p2":"disease2", "gender" : "M"})

p3 = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node("patients", "p3", "disease3", {"p3":"disease3", "gender" : "M","return":'yes'})

d1=graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node("doctors","d1",{"years_experience":"20","re-admission_rate":"20%"})
d2=graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node("doctors","d2",{"years_experience":"2","re-admission_rate":"40%"})
```

USING LABELS

```
patients=[{"patients", "p1", "disease1", {"p1":"disease1", "gender" : "F"}},{"patients", "p2", "disease2", {"p2":"disease2", "gender" : "M"}}]
doctors=[{"doctors","d1",{"years_experience":"20","re-admission_rate":"20%"}}]

for patient in patients:
    t=batch.create(patient)
    batch.add_labels(t,'Patient')
batch.submit()
batch.clear()
```

Also, if I want to batch add relationships (let's say patient1 visits doctor1 today and in one month), how do I do that? Do I add new relationship with a timestamp as a label?

Comment: This will help:   http://nigelsmall.com/neo4j/index-confusion

Comment: I have read that. However, it will help me greatly if someone could tell me if 2 approaches above are different in the sense of Cypher queries performed on created data and if they are, why.

Comment: For your second question, I'd probably model the "visit" as a node as you then can attach other information to it too. 

But yes otherwise you'd put a timestamp property on it.